# Nativescript: how do I include a view (e.g. a slide drawer) in several views?

Tags: telerik, nativescript

In my Nativescript (1.5.2) application I have my view **myDrawerView/myDrawerView.xml**.

In the view I have a drawer (part of [Telerik-Nativescript-UI](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/SideDrawer/sidedrawer-getting-started))

**myDrawerView.xml**

```
   <Page loaded="pageLoaded" xmlns:drawer="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
      <drawer:RadSideDrawer>
        <drawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
          <StackLayout cssClass="drawerContent">
            <StackLayout cssClass="headerContent">
              <Label text="Header"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout cssClass="drawerMenuContent">
              <Label text="Item 1"/>
              <Label text="Item 2"/>
              <Label text="Item 3"/>
              <Label text="Item 4"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>
        </drawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
      </drawer:RadSideDrawer>
    </Page>
```

I could include this very same drawer in each view where I need it, but this would result in a lot of replicated code.

Now let's say that I have 2 views:

- myView1/myView1.xml
- myView2/myView2.xml

For other components (part of **Nativescript core UI modules**: tns-core-modules) I could just take advantage of the view's controllers (**myView1.ts** and **myView2.ts**) by for example:

```
 var scrollView = new scrollViewModule.ScrollView();
```

However for this sideDrawer there is no mention of programmatic initialization in the docs linked.

The only solution I see here is to import somehow **myDrawer.xml** by "injecting" it in both **myView1.xml** and **myView2.xml**.
How do I make it or alternativaly what path can I follow to sort this problem out?